# How to insert clipboard content with a macro in Notepad++ per RegEx formula (alternative to ctrl + v) in the replace line window?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, clipboard, paste

Here is an example:

```
Search for: test
Replace with: clipboard content
```

---

Only static characters are added to the found. What I'm looking for could be this:

```
a

5
```

Search:

```
([a-z])|([0-9])
```

Replace:

```
\1\2
```

This is to append group 2 to group 1. If there is a solution for this, the clipboard is unnecessary. The result should be the following:

```
a5

5
```

Sense and purpose is to do it with several strings in the upper range.

```
a5
abc5
from5

5
```

Group 2 would have to be excluded with some kind of regex command, so that the addition only takes place for group 1. There must also be a limit (lookforward) that stops at an empty line so that replace all can be used. But I don't know how such a regex code should look like.

This:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

a A
b B
c C
d D
e E
```

should be this:

```
1.*a A|a A.*1| 2.*a A|a A.*2| 3.*a A|a A.*3| 4.*a A|a A.*4| 5.*a A|a A.*5| 6.*a A|a A.*6| 7.*a A|a A.*7| 8.*a A|a A.*8| 9.*a A|a A.*9| 10.*a A|a A.*10|1.*b B|b B.*1| 2.*b B|b B.*2| 3.*b B|b B.*3| 4.*b B|b B.*4| 5.*b B|b B.*5| 6.*b B|b B.*6| 7.*b B|b B.*7| 8.*b B|b B.*8| 9.*b B|b B.*9| 10.*b B|b B.*10|1.*c C|c C.*1| 2.*c C|c C.*2| 3.*c C|c C.*3| 4.*c C|c C.*4| 5.*c C|c C.*5| 6.*c C|c C.*6| 7.*c C|c C.*7| 8.*c C|c C.*8| 9.*c C|c C.*9| 10.*c C|c C.*10|1.*d D|d D.*1| 2.*d D|d D.*2| 3.*d D|d D.*3| 4.*d D|d D.*4| 5.*d D|d D.*5| 6.*d D|d D.*6| 7.*d D|d D.*7| 8.*d D|d D.*8| 9.*d D|d D.*9| 10.*d D|d D.*10|1.*e E|e E.*1| 2.*e E|e E.*2| 3.*e E|e E.*3| 4.*e E|e E.*4| 5.*e E|e E.*5| 6.*e E|e E.*6| 7.*e E|e E.*7| 8.*e E|e E.*8| 9.*e E|e E.*9| 10.*e E|e E.*10
```

Comment: You would need to paste your clipboard content in a new tab and perform a search for `\t` and replace it with `\\t` and ditto for `\r` and `\n`. Now you can copy that content and put into into the "Replace with:" box assuming your using "Extended" mode.

Comment: \t means tabulator. 0 occurences were replaced. Because I create a macro, the content must not match the clipboard content, because it' s unique words that should replace the search. Maybe there is a RegEx command that can be used to call the clipboard content to replace the search results.

Answer (score 0):

[edit:] If you just want to paste in text based on regex matches, you can use the below method for this too. Just follow the first part of my example, but paste in the clipboard content in the 'Replace with:' field instead of the replace text I used.

I commonly do this - if I'm understanding you correctly. It's completely possible to search on a regular expression and then replace matches with modified text that incorporates all, or parts of (groups within), the match. For instance if you want to convert a python function into a C expression:

```
def foo(x, y):   --->   int foo(int x, int y) {
```

You can open the replace menu in Notepad++ (ctrl-H), and in the 'Find what:' field put

```
def\s+([\w_]+)\(([\w_]+),\s*([\w_]+)\):
```

Then in the 'Replace with:' field put:

```
int \1\(int \2, int \3\) {
```

Then use either 'Find Next' to replace one instance at a time, or if you're a risk taker, 'Replace All'... of course my expression is only limited to functions that have two parameters. I kept it simple just for demo.

Comment: I just played around with the macro feature to see if what I suggest above is recordable and replayable.. yeah.. it works.  I never used that feature before.